# CSS Printer margin color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a html page that is "printable". However, when printing there is a big white border around the page while the background color is dark (see the image). My goal is to fill all the whites with the color of dark, while keeping the margins each page.

I tried:

- Removing the page margins when printing

  - This worked with the colors, however, I've now lost the margins.
- Setting "normal" html margins

  - This removed the margin per page.

What it looks like:

[image: What it looks like]

Comment: Please post a cut down version of your html and css